# Check if Carrierwave image version is exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

Using Carrierwave and Fog to upload images to to S3, I want to check if image version is exist.

I'm using this code (inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23578557/558777)) to check if it's exist or not

```
- if post.image_url(:thumb).file.exists?
  .media-cover{:style => "background-image: url(#{post.image_url(:thumb)}"}
```

But I'm getting this error

```
NoMethodError at /

undefined method `file' for #<String:0x007fb7ab7af980>
```

I can access the default version with `post.image_url`

Answer (score 2):

Well obviously it is returning the :thumb image_url and not the version itself, thus you cant get a file. You can just check with:

```
post.thumb.file.exists?
```

whether the thumb file exists, then use the url helper

Comment: I tried this but I get `undefined method thumb for` as there is not `thumb` method attached to the post object.

Comment: Do you have an entry for :thumb (size/ratio, etc) in your CarrierWave setup? The name could be anything you chose; not just :thumb.

Comment: @MattDarby Yes this is my setup for `:thumb`      as                                `version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [312, 170]
  end`